# Error on the VBA code for attachment

Tags: vba, attachment, dao, recordset

I'm trying to make a code for upload a few files but I get an error.
I´ve downloaded the file dao360.dll that is "DAO 3.6 object Library", because I had an error in the first line of code, when I load that reference that error on the first line vanished, but another one showed up.

Now I have error on the second line.

The code I have so far is:

```
Private Sub SaveToAttachmentField()
Dim rsRecord As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsAttach As DAO.Recordset2
Dim fldAttach As DAO.Field2
Dim dlgOpen As Office.FileDialog
Dim selFile As Variant

Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With dlgOpen
    .Title = "Selecionar fotos para adicionar ao registo"
    .ButtonName = "Selecione ficheiro(s)"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .InitialFileName = "Path:\to\default\folder"
    .Filters.Add "Imagens", "*.jpeg;*.jpg", 1
    If .Show <> 0 Then
    Me.Dirty = False
Set rsRecord = Me.RecordsetClone
    With rsRecord
    .Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
    .Edit
    Set rsAttach = .Fields("Anexo412").Value
        With rsAttach
        For Each selFile In dlgOpen.SelectedItems
            .AddNew
            .Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile selFile
            .Update
        Next
            End With
            .Update
        End With
    End If
End With

rsRecord.Close
Set rsRecord = Nothing
Set rsAttach = Nothing
Set dlgOpen = Nothing
End Sub
```

The compiler is giving a error in line `Dim rsAttach As DAO.Recordset2`, and the error says that "User defined was not defined"

Maybe something is missing in my root (maybe a .dll)

Comment: Now i had my problem solved. References in ms access where not set.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set up the references.
You need this: Microsoft access 15.0 Access database engine object library, Microsoft Office Object Library.
Problem solved